# VoIP - GSM calling via iOS

Tags: ios, sip, voip, gsm

I've spent days now searching for a way to route calls from an iOS application through a voip server to mobile number or fixed landline number (or send an SMS)... Essentially like voIP-GSM

I want to essentially have a similar system set up to Skype but with out the other user having the app, just directly call someone's phone using your data/wifi rather than your limited voice minutes or numbers if SMS.

One company who I know of that has worked out how to do this is: http://callsfreecalls.com/

I don't just want app-app communication like from twilio or rebtel!!

1) Would Asterisk or PJSIP help me in any way?
2) Would there be anyway I could do this all for free?
3) Will I have to create my own VoIP network or SIP server??
4) Will I be able to accomplish all this and put it into an iOS app?

Any ideas or help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  I'm also (still) looking

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

With Twilio Client you can make a VoIP connection from a mobile app into Twilio, then route that to any other number (mobile or landline).  You are not restricted to app-to-app only calls.

When you create a [Capability Token](http://www.twilio.com/docs/client/capability-tokens) for Twilio Client, one of the parameters you can pass it is a [TwiML Application SID](http://www.twilio.com/docs/client/capability-tokens#allow-outgoing-connections).  That TwiML Application maps to a URL that you can use to return TwiML instructions that Twilio will execute when a user initiates an outbound call from your iOS app.  In those instructions, you can use the [`<Dial>`](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) verb to tell Twilio to dial a regular [phone number](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number), which we will bridge to the Twilio Client connection.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I couldn't find anywhere in the documentation that enabled me to do that...?

Comment: I just read through the documentation again and could not find an answer...!

Comment: Updated my answer to have more info on how TwiML apps are used to provide TwiML that tells Twilio to dial a phone number

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Is that completely free? Would the user just pay for his/her calls and I'd pay for the twilio account? It looks really good and simple though! Just the free thing was big for me... THanks though

Comment: Here is info on Twilio Client pricing: http://www.twilio.com/client/pricing, and info on Twilio Voice pricing:  http://www.twilio.com/voice/pricing